# How to achieve instagram kind of image filter effect with Core Image

Tags: swift, swiftui, instagram, core-image

I have tried a few image filter effects in Core Image with SwiftUI. Like grouping different filters and connect relevant intensity with a Slider to change the filter's intensity.

I'm wondering is there a way to achieve the similar image filter effect like instagram. Because the single one of Core Image filter looks like not that fancy as instagram's. I guess chaining several effects in CI may achieve some of them on instagram, but I simply don't know which one to chain... No idea how to perform those filter effect according their name like "Sierra", "Willow".

So is there a way can achieve those filter effect in Core Image? Or some 3rd party library is needed? Any live example, project, framework/lib or hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most of Instagram's filters are achieved by simple lookup tables, i.e. using a map (image) for replacing colors with a mapped color. You can use the [`CIColorCube` filter](https://cifilter.io/CIColorCube/) to achieve something like that in Core Image. You can search the internet for example lookup tables (they usually come in the form of images). There is probably also example code on how to bring them into the right format.

Another thing Instagram does is adding a vignette effect. There is also a Core Image filter for that: [`CIVignetteEffect`](https://cifilter.io/CIVignetteEffect/).

Comment: Oh, you linked CIFilter.io, this doc I collected it before too, great one to preview some effects.

Comment: Have you any idea about how can achive "Tokyo", "Rio De Janerio", etc. type photo effect. This is a instagram add story page effect.